# How to remove inline style from font awesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

I have:

```
<i class="fa fa-4x fa-picture-o wow bounceIn text-primary clearing" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceIn; -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;"></i>`(font awesome).
```

I want to get rid of `style="visibility: visible;`.

Comment: Without your code impossible to *properly* help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Why would you need that? See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the specific style property `visibility`, you can use the jQuery `.css()` function and assign it a new empty value. That will result in it being removed as stated in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied...

In your case, you could do something like

```
$('i.clearing').css("visibility","");
```

Comment: Use `inherit` instead, empty string isn't valid property value and each browser could handle it differently

Comment: @A.Wolff I think with empty string the property is removed.

Comment: @R3tep Ya i guess but this should be tested on all browsers. Maybe jQuery as normalized it, not sure about it

Comment: @A.Wolff From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/) > $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied

Comment: @R3tep Thx to pointing it out!

Comment: @A.Wolff With native JavaScript you need to define to "null" to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property visibility to null to rid it :

```
<i id='myTag' class="fa fa-4x fa-picture-o wow bounceIn text-primary clearing" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: bounceIn; -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;"></i>
```

JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById('myTag').style.visibility = null;
```

*PS: I added an id to your tag `i` to find it with `getElementById`*